# unable to add accounts in online accounts Ubuntu 15.10 gnome 3.18

Tags: gnome, 15.10, online-accounts

When adding either google account or facebook, the authentication page pops up, but the accounts are not getting added. The original window has a black background and it is struck. If I invoke using command line also there is no error message. Kindly let me know how to debug this.

Thanks 
Krishna

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`sudo apt-get install gnome-online-accounts`

I had a same problem, this was solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But no luck. Looks like I will have to go back to 3.14